# success url not redirecting to the page i want

Tags: django

I have a CreateView class
where i set the success url like this

```
class ListCreateView(CreateView):
    model = List
    fields = "_all_"
    success_url = "list"
```

after submitting the form
Its going to

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/home/create_list/list
```

which doesnt exist

I want it to go to

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/home/list
```

can anyone help with some suggestions? I tried reverselazy but that brings up another big error. and im a noob.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to go to `/home/list` that should be your `success_url`.
And if you have named your views, you can do it by `reverse_lazy()`.

Something like:

```py
class ListCreateView(CreateView):
    model = List
    fields = "_all_"
    success_url = "/home/list/"
    # or if you named your urls in urls.py
    success_url = reverse_lazy("home:list")
```